# Refactor of ShouldSerialize () in class... can I use IContractResolver?

Tags: c#, api, serialization, json.net

I have an API that returns a big list of car features.... all are either bool or ints... and basically I only want to display the ones that return true values or >0 for the ints.

I am using JSON.net so that I san use the ShouldSerialize() property to determine if I should serialize the property based upon its value and my code looks like this:

```
public class Features
{
    public bool ABS { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeABS()
    {
        // don't serialize the ABS property if ABS is false
        return (ABS != false);
    }


    public bool Immobiliser { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeImmobiliser ()
    {
        // don't serialize the Immobiliser property if Immobiliser is false
        return (Immobiliser != false);
    }

    public int BHP { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeBHP  ()
    {
        // don't serialize the BHP property if BHP is false
        return (BHP != 0);
    }
    //..... etc
}
```

This works great and gives me the results I am after, however I was just wondering if there is a way to re-factor this so that my class does not become cluttered with all the ShouldSerialize() properties?

I have been looking into `CopyConditional` properties with `IContractResolver` on http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConditionalProperties.htm and looks like it might be possible to use `IContractResolver` for such a purpose, but I still seem to end up with lots of code that does not seem to re-factor out

```
public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
   public new static readonly ShouldSerializeContractResolver Instance = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver();

   protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
   {
     JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

     if (property.DeclaringType == typeof(Features) && property.PropertyName == "ABS")
     {
         property.ShouldSerialize =
           instance =>
           {
               Features e = (Features)instance;
               return e.ABS != false;
           };
     }
     if (property.DeclaringType == typeof(Features) && property.PropertyName == "Immobiliser")
     {
         property.ShouldSerialize =
           instance =>
           {
               Features e = (Features)instance;
               return e.Immobiliser != false;
           };
     }

    return property;
  }
}
```

and this method using the ShouldSerializeContractResolver does not seem to remove the property from the class if it is false... any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you are trying to accomplish by writing all these ShouldSerialize() methods can be accomplished by just changing the `DefaultValueHandling` setting on the serializer to Ignore.  This will cause any values that are equal to their default values (false for bool, 0 for int) not to be serialized.

```
JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject, jsonSettings);
```

If you're using Web API, then you can access the settings of the Json.NET serializer via the `Register` method of the `WebApiConfig` class (in the App_Start folder).

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
settings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
```