# Json.Net ShouldSerialize* used

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api

My question is similar to [Refactor of ShouldSerialize () in class... can I use IContractResolver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317026/refactor-of-shouldserialize-in-class-can-i-use-icontractresolver) but my use case is not so simple. I am wondering if there is a simple way to do something like ShouldSerialize* in a base class or something so that I don't have to add a ShouldSerilize{MemberName} for every property I want to decide whether to serialize?

Comment: AFAIK there is no other way to filter all properties. Just with IContractResolver. That is the interface that can provide changing of serialization behavior at runtime. For simplicity, where you know that all your properties must be serialized you can get rid of reset, should serialize methods and use default value approach. This is my opinion.

Comment: It would help if you described your use case in more detail.  What would be the logic that would determine whether a property is to be serialized or not?  And would this apply to all classes / properties or just some?